# For loop in list

Tags: f#, control-flow

Poeple often use

```
for i in [0 .. 10] do something
```

but afaik that creates a list which is then iterated through, it appears to me it would make more sense to use

```
for i = 0 to 10 do something
```

without creating that unnecessary list but having the same behaviour.
Am I missing something? (I guess that's the case)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct, writing `for i in [0 .. 10] do something` generates a list and it does have a significant overhead. Though you can also omit the square brackets, in which case it just builds a lazy sequence (and, it turns out that the compiler even optimizes that case). I generally prefer writing `in 0 .. 100 do` because it looks the same as code that iterates over a sequence.

Using the `#time` feature of F# interactive to do a simple analysis:

```
for i in [ 0 .. 10000000 ] do // 3194ms (yikes!)
  last <- i

for i in 0 .. 10000000 do     // 3ms
  last <- i

for i = 0 to 10000000 do      // 3ms
  last <- i

for i in seq { 0 .. 10000000 } do // 709ms (smaller yikes!)
  last <- i
```

So, it turns out that the compiler actually optimizes the `in 0 .. 10000000 do` into the same thing as the `0 to 10000000 do` loop. You can force it to create the lazy sequence explicitly (last case) which is faster than a list, but still very slow.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I tried this on mono with the llvm optimizer enabled. It didn't help; I  got substantially the same results.

Comment: I am not sure the first alternative is inefficient in terms of computation speed (it is inefficient in terms of memory usage). The second and third alternatives did not calculate anything, that is why they are so "fast."

Answer (score 7):

*Giving a somewhat different kind of answer but hopefully interesting to some*

You are correct in that the F# compiler fails to apply the fast-for-loop optimization in this case. Good news, the F# compiler is open source and it's possible for us to improve upon it's behavior.

So here's a freebie from me:

fast-for-loop optimization happens in [tastops.fs](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/tastops.fs). It's rather primitive at the moment, great opportunity for us to improve upon.

```
// Detect the compiled or optimized form of a 'for <elemVar> in <startExpr> .. <finishExpr>  do <bodyExpr>' expression over integers
// Detect the compiled or optimized form of a 'for <elemVar> in <startExpr> .. <step> .. <finishExpr>  do <bodyExpr>' expression over integers when step is positive
let (|CompiledInt32ForEachExprWithKnownStep|_|) g expr = 
    match expr with 
    | Let (_enumerableVar, RangeInt32Step g (startExpr, step, finishExpr), _, 
           Let (_enumeratorVar, _getEnumExpr, spBind,
              TryFinally (WhileLoopForCompiledForEachExpr (_guardExpr, Let (elemVar,_currentExpr,_,bodyExpr), m), _cleanupExpr))) -> 

        let spForLoop = match spBind with SequencePointAtBinding(spStart) -> SequencePointAtForLoop(spStart) |  _ -> NoSequencePointAtForLoop 

        Some(spForLoop,elemVar,startExpr,step,finishExpr,bodyExpr,m)
    | _ -> 
        None

let DetectFastIntegerForLoops g expr = 
    match expr with 
    | CompiledInt32ForEachExprWithKnownStep g (spForLoop,elemVar,startExpr,step,finishExpr,bodyExpr,m) 
         // fast for loops only allow steps 1 and -1 steps at the moment
         when step = 1 || step = -1 -> 
            mkFastForLoop  g (spForLoop,m,elemVar,startExpr,(step = 1),finishExpr,bodyExpr)
    | _ -> expr
```

The problem here is that `RangeInt32Step` only detects patterns like `0..10` and `0..1..10`. It misses for instance `[0..10]`

Let's introduce another active pattern `SeqRangeInt32Step` that matches these kind of expressions:

```
let (|SeqRangeInt32Step|_|) g expr =
    match expr with
    // detect '[n .. m]'
    | Expr.App(Expr.Val(toList,_,_),_,[TType_var _],
                [Expr.App(Expr.Val(seq,_,_),_,[TType_var _],
                          [Expr.Op(TOp.Coerce, [TType_app (seqT, [TType_var _]); TType_var _],
                                    [RangeInt32Step g (startExpr, step, finishExpr)], _)],_)],_)
        when
            valRefEq g toList (ValRefForIntrinsic g.seq_to_list_info) &&
            valRefEq g seq g.seq_vref &&
            tyconRefEq g seqT g.seq_tcr ->
            Some(startExpr, step, finishExpr)

    | _ -> None
```

How do you figure out that this is what you need to pattern match for? The approach I often take is that I do a simple F# program with the right properties and put a breakpoint during compilation to inspect the expression. From that I create the pattern to match for:

Let's put the two patterns together:

```
let (|ExtractInt32Range|_|) g expr =
  match expr with
  | RangeInt32Step g range -> Some range
  | SeqRangeInt32Step g range -> Some range
  | _ -> None
```

`CompiledInt32ForEachExprWithKnownStep` is updated to use `ExtractInt32Range` over `RangeInt32Step`

The complete solution would be something like this:

```
let (|SeqRangeInt32Step|_|) g expr =
    match expr with
    // detect '[n .. m]'
    | Expr.App(Expr.Val(toList,_,_),_,[TType_var _],
                [Expr.App(Expr.Val(seq,_,_),_,[TType_var _],
                          [Expr.Op(TOp.Coerce, [TType_app (seqT, [TType_var _]); TType_var _],
                                    [RangeInt32Step g (startExpr, step, finishExpr)], _)],_)],_)
        when
            valRefEq g toList (ValRefForIntrinsic g.seq_to_list_info) &&
            valRefEq g seq g.seq_vref &&
            tyconRefEq g seqT g.seq_tcr ->
            Some(startExpr, step, finishExpr)

    | _ -> None

let (|ExtractInt32Range|_|) g expr =
  match expr with
  | RangeInt32Step g range -> Some range
  | SeqRangeInt32Step g range -> Some range
  | _ -> None

// Detect the compiled or optimized form of a 'for <elemVar> in <startExpr> .. <finishExpr>  do <bodyExpr>' expression over integers
// Detect the compiled or optimized form of a 'for <elemVar> in <startExpr> .. <step> .. <finishExpr>  do <bodyExpr>' expression over integers when step is positive
let (|CompiledInt32ForEachExprWithKnownStep|_|) g expr = 
    match expr with 
    | Let (_enumerableVar, ExtractInt32Range g (startExpr, step, finishExpr), _,
           Let (_enumeratorVar, _getEnumExpr, spBind,
              TryFinally (WhileLoopForCompiledForEachExpr (_guardExpr, Let (elemVar,_currentExpr,_,bodyExpr), m), _cleanupExpr))) -> 

        let spForLoop = match spBind with SequencePointAtBinding(spStart) -> SequencePointAtForLoop(spStart) |  _ -> NoSequencePointAtForLoop 

        Some(spForLoop,elemVar,startExpr,step,finishExpr,bodyExpr,m)
    | _ -> 
        None
```

Using a simple test program

```
let print v =
    printfn "%A" v

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    for x in [0..10] do
        print x

    0
```

Before the optimization the corresponding C# code would look something like this (IL code is better to inspect but can be a bit hard to understand if one is unused to it):

```
// Test
[EntryPoint]
public static int main(string[] argv)
{
    FSharpList<int> fSharpList = SeqModule.ToList<int>(Operators.CreateSequence<int>(Operators.OperatorIntrinsics.RangeInt32(0, 1, 10)));
    IEnumerator<int> enumerator = ((IEnumerable<int>)fSharpList).GetEnumerator();
    try
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Test.print<int>(enumerator.Current);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

F# creates a list and then uses the enumerator to iterate over it. No wonder it's rather slow compared to a classic for-loop.

After the optimization is applied we get this code:

```
// Test
[EntryPoint]
public static int main(string[] argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        Test.print<int>(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A significant improvement.

So steal this code, post a PR to https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/ and bask in glory. Of course you need to add unit tests and emitted IL code tests which can be somewhat tricky to find the right level for, check this [commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/commit/76ae08d427a41e4140ca83a84d5479cc6007a529) for inspiration

PS. Probably should support `[|0..10|]` as well `seq {0..10}` as well

PS. In addition `for v in 0L..10L do print v` as well as `for v in 0..2..10 do print v` is also inefficiently implemented in F#.

Comment: Realized the active pattern should be named `ListRangeInt32Step` instead of `SeqRangeInt32Step`

Comment: Well I'm certainly thankful for your effort but this is a bit too in-depth for me, unfortunately. I am not familiar with running tests not using github.

Answer (score 0):

The former form requires a special construct in the language (for var from ... to ... by), it is the way followed by ancient programming languages :

- 'do' loop in Fortran
- for var:= expr to expr in Pascal
- etc.

The latter form (for var in something) is more général. It works on plain lists, but also with generators (like in python) etc. A construction of the full list may not be needed before running the list. This allows to write loops on potentially infinite lists.

Anyway, a decent compiler/interpreter should recognize the rather frequent special case [expr1..expr2] and avoid the computation and storage of the intermediate list.

Comment: A small notice: In F# lists are non-lazy meaning [0..100] creates a list with 101 elements whether they are consumed or not. seq {0..100} is lazy.